Why has my comment that a claim is apparently not serious been deleted?
I pointed out under this Q that prominently-posted rules of that subreddit appear to prohibit the very post made there.

YSKs regarding Reddit, Facebook, Twitter or any other social media are NOT ALLOWED.


I wrote that the whole YSK appears to be a joke subreddit. The comments in the very thread linked were in part like that.
So why has my comment on the seriousness of the post been deleted? Humour/joke claims are generally not entertained here, unless there's evidence a lot of people take them seriously. Something begin simply upvoted or signed is not considered enough.
And yeah, the post also claims the AI is making "lots" of spelling mistakes, which a lot of the comments concluded was a big part of the joke.

And lest I be accused of leaving out the most upvoted/'serious' commentary:


Which deleted comment are you talking about?
Was it this one?

TBH most of the Reddit contents are one-line quips that you've read 100 times before. AI is quite capable of that.

That one was an unreferenced pseudo-answer. It didn't attempt to clarify the question or ask for clarification.
Or was it this one?

Funnily enough the YSK post is in violation of YSK rules: "YSKs regarding Reddit, Facebook, Twitter or any other social media are NOT ALLOWED." I think the whole YSK subreddit is a joke one, so this is not a serious claim. You've been trolled successfully.

The first sentence is a comment about whether the post followed the rules of another forum. Totally irrelevant.
The second sentence is an unreferenced pseudo-answer. We don't accept joke claims, but it is entirely unclear that this is a joke claim - I disagree with your opinion that the posts on that forum are always jokes - so it is just begging the question.
The third sentence is just being mean for no reason.
Either way, on this site comments are second-class citizens and pseudo-answers aren't tolerated, so they were both deleted.

I meant the 2nd one. And if 'pseudo answers' are not allowed, why haven't you deleted this "I don't know about the "AI" part, but bots (and humans) posting old content as if it was their own is a longstanding problem on Reddit. --Mark". Or your own comment about non-AI bots. "I've seen a common phenomenon on Reddit that a popular comment on a popular post will be repeated under a different comment [...]" How are those not pseudo-answers as well?

My comment was intended to seek clarification about whether it counts; the claim is a little vague, and I didn't want to post an answer that tackled a strawman. Thanks for drawing my attention to Mark's comment - deleted.

Fair enough. The OP here did write 'AI' in their own words at the end of the question, but what counts as AI for them is indeed not said. OTOH there was a prior discussion here that if the original claimant doesn't define terms, then answers could assume the common meaning[s]. https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3230/how-much-we-need-to-define-in-a-question

... in fact more than one on the latter https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3501/how-to-rigourously-define-happiness-or-quality-of-life ; https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2177/how-to-handle-questions-that-lead-to-arguments-about-definitions

As for 'AI', I think we probably need some kind of general discussion if the term is in general too vague, and so when should some question with 'AI' thrown in there be  answered nonetheless ignoring any discussion about what qualifies as AI.
